# Upgrade from Win 8 to Win 8 pro without formatting

Tags: windows-8

I am starting to develop win 8 apps, but I can't run the emulator because I don't have win 8 pro installed.

I have the regular win 8, so I am asking, if it is possible to upgrade from win 8 to win 8 pro without formatting my computer

I have tried the "Add functions to win 8", but when I enter my new product key(with CTRL-C), it says the key doesn't work

Comment: It was because of the key I got. I contacted the place I got it, and they told me, that the key couldn't be used for the "Add features to Windows 8". So I had to format

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you can upgrade from standard Windows 8 installation to a Windows 8 Pro edition quite easily.

Follow the instructions found on this Microsoft Windows Help link: [Add features to Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/feature-packs)

Hope this helps you some.

Comment: I have tried that several times. But it keeps saying wrong key. I bought a key for Win 8 Pro N. :(